# Why is a Order-Product relationship many to many?

Tags: database, many-to-many

In database design, one order can have multiple products, which is no problem. But one product can always be only in one order, isn't it? For example, how can the same iPhone be placed in two different orders?

I think it should be a one to many relationship, instead of many to many. What's wrong with the logic?

Answer (score 13):

Say you are an e-commerce company and have 70000 IPhones in stock.

According to the design you are suggesting, in your "Product" DB table you would store 70000 rows (1 row for each IPhone). This way each "Order" will reference a unique IPhone. Do you see how quickly your db would have a data explosion.

What you should do instead is store the general characteristics of an IPhone (name, price, brand etc) in 1 row of the table and to keep track of the inventory count using a column called "inventory"

Something like this below (Note you can improve this design below further but this will be sufficient to understand the many-to-many logic here)

```
Product
-------------
id | name   | brand | price | inventory
1  | IPhone | Apple | 600   | 70000
```

Now for every order that has an IPhone in it, the order will reference the same row of the product table. Hence 1 product will be in multiple orders.

Let me know if you need any more clarification. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

the answer is that  one order can have many products and also one product can belongs to many orders 
as an example:
you can order many books from an E-commerce website and any book can be ordered many times

Answer (score 0):

Product-Order many to many relationship means that in one order u can order many products e.g. you can buy many products at once and seller will give you one receipt (one order). And the opposite site is one product type can be sealed many times e.g. store ordered (import) iPhone and sealed it. It turns out that the same product has many orders.
For more information have look at [Many-to-many (data model)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_(data_model))  in Wikipedia.

Hope i helped you!